# ZendFramework: Changing a form element after failed validation

Tags: forms, zend-framework

So I have a form set up in the following manner:

In my forms directory:

Address.php

```
class Address extends Zend_Form{
    // Creates an address input box including address/country/state/zip
    // The states is created as a drop down menu 
    public function init() {
         // relevant code to question
         $this->addElements(array(
            array('select', $names['state'], array(
                'label'        => "State",
                'class'        => 'state',
                'multiOptions' => array('' => '') + AddressHelper::stateList(),
                'required'     => $this->_required,
            )),
         ));
    }
}
```

MyForm.php:

```
class MyForm extends Zend_Form {
  public function init() {
    //set-up some general form info 

    // this is the relevant part for my question
    // $opt is a predefined variable
    $this->addSubForms(array(
            'info' => new SubForm($opts),
            'mailing' => new Address($opts + array(
                'legend' => 'Address', 
                'isArray' => false, 
                'required' => true,
        )),
    ));  
   }
}
```

Survey.php

```
class Survey extends MyForm{
    // initialize parent (MyForm) and add additional info for the Survey form
}
```

Okay, so when survey is submitted, if it fails validation, I need to change the Address state element from a select to an input type=text.

So in my controller, under the action that checks for validation I have the following:

```
public function createAction(){
     if ($this->_form->isValid($post)) {
        $this->_saveDraft($post, $this->_submissionType);
        $this->addSessionMessage('Submission created!');
        return $this->redirector->gotoRouteAndExit(array(), 'home', true);
     }else{
        /* IMPORTANT */
        // I need to change the Address select field to a text field here!

        $errors[] = 'There was a problem';
        $this->view->assign(compact('form', 'errors', 'submission'));
        $this->_viewRenderer->renderScript('update.phtml');
     }
}
```

So, would I just create a method in the Address class and somehow call it to swap out. I'm just not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be looking at using `removeElement()` to remove the select element, and then `addElement()` to replace it with the text only version.

The problem you are going to have is that when the validation fails, the select element is changed to a text element and the form is re-displayed.  Now, upon resubmission, you need to make the change again prior to calling `isValid()` because the form uses text input for state instead of select.  So you need to make the change twice.  Once after failed validation prior to re-displaying the form, and once prior to calling `isValid()`, but only if there was a previously failed submission.

Now why is it that if the form fails validation, you want the select element for state to be text?  Can't it work just the same with a select element and you just pre-select the correct state for them?

EDIT:

You use the form object to call add/removeElement.

```
$removed = $form->getSubForm('mailing')->removeElement('state_select');
$form->getSubForm('mailing')->addElement($text_state_element);
```

That call should work to remove an element from a subform.

Without subforms, it is just:

```
$form->removeElement('username');
$form->addElement($someNewElement);
```

You can use `getElement()` in a similar way if you need to get an element from a form to make changes (e.g. remove/add validators, change description, set values)

```
$el = $form->getElement('username');
$el->addValidator($something)
   ->setLabel('Username:');
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Nice avatar... but how do I removeElement? What object do I need to call to do that?

Comment: Thx, was gonna say the same about yours.  Edited answer with extra explanation.